# ROS Answers SE migration: CMakeList.txt

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
I want to include so moveit headers in my CMakeList.txt, because when I run catkin_make this error comes up

```
CMkeFiles/inv_node.dir/src/inv_node.cpp.o: In function 'main':
inv_node.cpp:(.text+0x33f): undefined reference to 'rdf_loader::RDFLoader::RDFLoader(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/youbot/catkin_wsj/devel/lib/inv_node/inv_node] Error 1
make[1]: *** [inv_node/CMakeFiles/inv_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error2
```

Can anyone say me what I have to writte in my CMakeList.txt that it works?

That would be grade.

Thanks.

this is a part of my code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <urdf/model.h>

// MoveIt!
#include <moveit/robot_model/robot_model.h>
#include <moveit/robot_state/robot_state.h>
#include <moveit/rdf_loader/rdf_loader.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "inv_node");
  ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
  spinner.start();

 ros::NodeHandle nh;

// Convert urdf file in a string
  std::ifstream u("youbot_arm.urdf");
  std::stringstream su;
  su << u.rdbuf();

// upload the urdf to the parameter server
  nh.setParam("robot_description", su.str());

  // Convert srdf file in a string
  std::ifstream s("youbot.srdf");
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << s.rdbuf();

// upload the srdf to the parameter server
  nh.setParam("robot_description_semantic", ss.str());


// Initialize the robot model
// Objekt robot_model wird initialisiert durch Konstruktor der Klasse
  rdf_loader::RDFLoader::RDFLoader robot_model(su.str(), ss.str());

ros::shutdown();
return 0;
}
```

my CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimu_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(inv_node)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  moveit_core
  roscpp
  rospy
  urdf
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES inv_node
  CATKIN_DEPENDS moveit_core roscpp rospy urdf
  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  opt/hydro/include/moveit/rdf_loader/rdf_loader.h
)

add_executable(inv_node src/inv_node.cpp)
target_link_libraries(inv_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(inv_node inv_node_gencpp)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293155/cmakelist.txt/) by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you need to `find_package` `moveit_ros_planning` (this is where the `rdf_loader` is located) and add it as a dependency in the `package.xml`.

This finds the library (what you have is a linker error) and populates the `catkin_LIBRARIES` variable (amongst others) accordingly. This also alows you to get rid of the ugly hard-coded path in the `include_directories` section.

Lastly, I'll highly recommend to upgrade to a more up-to-date ROS distro, as hydro is EOL. If you need a LTS, choose either kinetic (old, but everything should be available there) or melodic (brand-new, but not everything already available).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on 2018-06-04**:
Now I have a error: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
I don't know if i store the headers in the right directory.
Directory opt/ros/hydro/include/moveit/rdf_loader contains the header-file rdf_loader

**Comment by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on 2018-06-04**:
Directory opt/ros/hydro/include/moveit_ros_planning contains PlanExecutionDynamicReconfigureConfig.h, PlanningSceneMonitorDynamicReconfigureConfig.h, ...

My executable is in my workspace /home/catkin_wsj/src/inv_node/src

Is this a good way?

**Comment by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on 2018-06-04**:
Thanks for your help :)

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-06-04**:
You shouldn't need to manually add that include directory if the rest of your CMakeLists.txt file is correct. That said, the error you are mentioning is likely because of the missing "/" at the beginning of `/opt/....`.

**Comment by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on 2018-06-04**:
Thanks. Now it works.

**Comment by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on 2018-06-06**:
@mig Do you have experience by using KDL PLugins for computing inverse kinematics?

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-06-07**:
@JonasG this is probably not a great place to ask this question as your KDL comment has nothing to do with the original question. If you'd like to ask something specific about IK with KDL, I'd suggest opening a new question or posting to the MoveIt! Users google group if the question is about MoveIt